# Issue adding map to container in for each loop.

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, each, leaflet

I wanna add Leaflet map for each JSON object's element, but error log says that can't find container for a map.

```
 success:
 $.each(json, function(i, data) {
 newhtml +='<div class="info">'+data.info+'</div>=<div class="story_map" id=story_map'+data.post_id+'></div>';

            var container = "story_map"+data.post_id;
            var map = L.map(container, {scrollWheelZoom:false,dragging:false}).setView([50, 50], 3);
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/4bf7e7a40966461892sdfafac6eb4838/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);
 }

 $('#stream').append(newhtml);
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `newhtml` method to include the new div, but aren't actually adding it to the page until later - and before you add it to the page, you try to initialize the map. So basically move `$('#stream').append(newhtml);` up in your code to after `newhtml` and instead of appending newhtml together just do

```
 newhtml ='<div class="info">'+data.info+'</div>=<div class="story_map" id=story_map'+data.post_id+'></div>';
```